# Send multiple attachments with Grails Async Mail Plugin

Tags: email, grails, plugins, groovy

I am using grails Async Mail plugin to send emails with attachments in my app. to achieve that I have written following code

```
def sendEmail = {
    def documentsInstances = Documents.getAll(params.list('ids[]'))
    def s3Service = new AmazonS3Service()
    documentsInstances.each(){documentsInstance->
            asyncMailService.sendMail {
                multipart true
                to documentsInstance.author.emailAddress
                subject 'Test';
                html '<body><u>Test</u></body>';
                attachBytes documentsInstance.filename , 'text/plain', s3Service.getBytes(session.uid,documentsInstance.filename);
            }
    }//

}
```

Now the code above works pretty much correctly but it sends an email per attachment, I am not sure how can I move this loop inside send mail so that I can send multiple attachments in an email.

Also is there a way to send an email so that I don't have to load a whole file in byte[]?

I am using JetS3t for access to Amazon S3 and I tried "attach" method with

`new InputStreamResource(s3Obj.getDataInputStream())`  ie

```
attach documentsInstance.filename , 'text/plain', new InputStreamResource(s3Obj.getDataInputStream());
```

but I am getting

`"Passed-in Resource contains an open stream: invalid argument. JavaMail requires an InputStreamSource that creates a fresh stream for every call"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need your loop *inside* the email:

```
def sendEmail = {
    def documentsInstances = Documents.getAll(params.list('ids[]'))
    def s3Service = new AmazonS3Service()
    asyncMailService.sendMail {
        multipart true
        to documentsInstance.author.emailAddress
        subject 'Test';
        html '<body><u>Test</u></body>';

        // loop over attachments
        documentsInstances.each{ documentsInstance->
            attachBytes documentsInstance.filename , 'text/plain', s3Service.getBytes(session.uid, documentsInstance.filename);
        }
    }
}
```

This should attach multiple files.

If it throws an error about not being able to find an `attachBytes` method, you might need to explicitly call `owner.attachBytes` instead, which should refer to the outer `sendMail` closure.

---

Update based on comments:

The Async plugin looks like it defers to the normal mail plugin.  The normal mail plugin's docs describes [how to use multiple attachments](http://gpc.github.com/grails-mail/docs/guide/3.%20Sending%20Email.html#3.3%20Attachments).

This would look something like:

```
   // loop over attachments
    documentsInstances.each{ documentsInstance->
        attach documentsInstance.filename , 'text/plain', s3Service.getBytes(session.uid, documentsInstance.filename);
      //^^^^^^ Notice, just 'attach', not 'attachBytes'
    }
```

I don't know the S3 plugin you are using, but if there is a way to retrieve an `InputStreamSource` from it, it appears that you can stream the bytes directly to the mail plugin, instead of loading them into memory.

Comment: Looks like attachBytes is deprecated and the docs are out of date, look at the "attach" methods in the plugin src for MailMessageBuilder

Comment: Ah, if the async plugin defers to the straight mail plugin, then [this page of the mail plugin](http://gpc.github.com/grails-mail/docs/guide/3.%20Sending%20Email.html#3.3%20Attachments) may help getting multiple attachments working correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried moving the loop in "sendMail" and I was getting an error about not being able to find attachBytes method. But now it's working with your solution. I am using JetS3t for my service and I tried "attach" method with new InputStreamResource(s3Obj.getDataInputStream()) but I am getting "Passed-in Resource contains an open stream: invalid argument. JavaMail requires an InputStreamSource that creates a fresh stream for every call"

Comment: @OverZealous I tried to circumvent the problem of InputStream by creating my own class which implements InputStreamSrouce but now in the same code I am getting groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.fluffystorage.DocumentsController.attach() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.fluffystorage.AmazonS3Resource) Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Check what I said above: you might have to call `owner.attach` instead.  It appears that it's looking for the attach method on `DocumentsController`.  If that doesn't work, try `delegate.attach` or `this.attach` (although I doubt those are right).  Alternatively, you might be dealing with the issue that the Async mail plugin doesn't support `attach` at all.

Comment: link above in answer is outdated